# 回答を承認するとどうなりますか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問

- 回答を承認するとどうなりますか？
- どの回答を承認すればいいですか？
- 満足する回答が得られない時は？

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 回答の承認

質問者は寄せられた回答の中から一つ選び、「承認済み」マークを付けることができます。回答を承認することで問題を解決してくれた人へのお礼になるほか、「この質問は解決済みですよ」と他のユーザーに示す意味合いもあります。（他サイトで言うベストアンサーのようなものです）

回答を承認するには、回答の左側にあるグレーのチェックマークをクリックして緑色に変えます。

[image: チェック前後の画面キャプチャ]

#### 細かい仕様

- 承認できる回答は1つだけですが、いつでも選び直したり、承認を取り消すことができます。
- 質問を投稿してから[15分間](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer)は回答を承認することができません。
- 自分でつけた回答を承認することもできます。この場合は質問投稿から48時間経過する必要があります。

承認された回答は他の回答より上に表示されるようになります。

また質問者に **+2** 点、承認された回答の投稿者に **+15** 点の信用度が与えられます。

ただし次の場合は除きます。

- *質問者自身による回答* : 信用度は与えられず、回答の表示順も変わりません。
- *[コミュニティWiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/) 回答* : 信用度は与えられません。

#### どの回答を承認すればいいですか？

あなたが個人的に最も役に立つと感じた回答を選べば大丈夫です。一般には、よく書けていて、いい方法を提示し、あなたの問題を見事解決してくれた回答ということになります。

ただし、その回答がきちんと問題が解決するかどうか、間違っていないか注意してください。他の人が間違いを指摘するかもしれません。念のため1～2日待ってみてもよいでしょう。

寄せられた回答はヒントにはなったけど、結局別の方法を自分で見つけた、という場合にはそれをご自身で投稿して承認しても構いません。「この質問者はこの方法で解決した」という目印になるように、最終的な解決策が承認されているのがベストです。

#### プラス投票

回答の承認とあわせてプラス投票をするのもいいでしょう。

- プラス投票をすることで、回答者に **+10** 点の信用度が与えられます。
- プラス投票は一つの回答でなくても構いませんから、他にも役立った回答があればぜひ投票してあげてください。

#### 満足する回答が得られない時は？

- 質問文を見直して、何が問題なのか、何を訊きたいのかが明確になっているかどうか確認してください。疑問点を一行に要約したものを書き加えたほうがいいかもしれません。
- 質問してから数日待って、新しくわかったことを質問に追記してみましょう。追加情報は回答の手助けになりますし、一覧のトップに表示されることで新しい人に見てもらえるかもしれません。
- 信用度を**75点以上**持っているなら、質問後2日経てば[懸賞を設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)することができます。