# ベストアンサーの　振り付け方。

Tags: サポート

いい　回答を
頂きましたので、
ベストアンサーを　割り振りたく、
思います、

しかし　方法が、
判りません。
"

其処で、

検索して　見ましたが、[image: 見ましたが、]
此の　様に、
示されません。
"

伺います、

対象は　メタ、
環境は　iOS14.5.1、
参照は　ブラウザ、
使用ブラウザは　Firefox、Safari、
なのですが。
"

如何すれば、

ベストアンサーを　割り振れるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ヘルプの [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  を参考にしてください。

要点を抜粋すると…

> 回答を承認済みとマークするには、回答の横にあるチェックマークをクリックしてグレー表示からチェック済みに切り替えます。

Comment: 有り難うございます。

Answer (score 3):

ベストアンサーは別のサイトの言葉ですね。
このサイトでは「承認」という言葉を使いますのでご了承ください。

承認については以下のリンクを参考にしてください。
[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
[回答が「承認された」とはどういう意味ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)
[回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)

Comment: 有り難うございます。